# Apache serve different index.html based on REQUEST_URI

Tags: html, angularjs, apache

I have the following configuration to serve only `index.html` if file or folder doesn't exist, to use with AngularJS.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/folder

    RewriteEngine On  
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteRule ^ /index.html

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/angular.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/angular.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What I would like to do is:
Check `REQUEST_URI` if starts with lang prefix like ru|es|gr, prepend this 2 letters to `index.html`

So  if access `example.com` apache will serve index.html from current root but if I access `example.com/ru` apache will serve `index.html` from `DOCUMENT_ROOT` + ru folder /ru/index.html

I've made something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/folder

    RewriteEngine On  
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(ru|es|gr)/
    RewriteRule ^ $1/index.html

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/angular.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/angular.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

But doesn't seems working.

Comment: I think by default web server will serve `index.html` from respective folder if file name is not specified. Try to remove the rules?

Comment: @Icycool Hi, When accesing `example/ru` yes it will serve `index.html` correctly, but when accessing  `example/ru/somepage/subpage/` it will serve `index.html` from root because this folder doesn't exist, but it start with `ru` so I need `/ru/index.html` to be served.

Comment: how about adding a slash in front? `RewriteRule ^ /$1/index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using $1, but this type of variable reference only applies to captured groups from rewriterule not from rewritecond, and you captured nothing in rewriterule, the correct thing would be to do it in 1 single directive:

```
RewriteRule ^/(ru|es|gr)/ /$1/index.html
```

OR if you insist on using an otherwise unneeded rewritecond, using the proper captured variable, note captured groups from rewriteconds use % symbol instead of $:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(ru|es|gr)/
RewriteRule ^ /%1/index.html
```

Note: You may be missing an L flag in this one.

Comment: Thank you this worked `RewriteRule ^/(ru|es|gr)/ /$1/index.html` very simple, thank you.